# Mongoose - find documents with maximum no of counts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean.io

I am using Mongoose to fetch data from MongoDB. Here is my model.

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      viewCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      description: {
        type: String,
        default: 'No description'
      },
      departments: []

    });
```

I need to find top 5 employees where count(viewCount) is highest order by name.

I am thinking of finding all the employee by using find() & then read viewCount property & produce the result. is there any better way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is [`.sort()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and [`.limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/):

```js
Employee.find().sort({ "viewCount": -1, "name": 1 }).limit(5)
    .exec(function(err,results) {

});
```

And that is the top 5 employees in views ordered by name after the viewCount.

If you want them ordered by "name" in your final five, then just sort that result:

```js
Employee.find().sort({ "viewCount": -1, "name": 1 }).limit(5)
    .exec(function(err,results) {
    // sort it by name
    results.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    });
    // do something with results
});
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind `{ "viewCount": -1, "name": 1 }` condition.

Comment: @SharpCoder There is a link to `.sort()` in the answer which shows you that these are the keys to sort and order of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the view count and limit the search results to 5.

In code it might look like this:

```
Employee
.find()
.sort([['viewCount',-1], ['name',-1]])
.limit(5)
.exec(function(err, results){
  //do something with the results here
});
```